# Is there a way to filter the results of a query by comparing the value of an aggregate function to a column that is not included in the GROUP BY?

Tags: sql

I am assuming the answer is no, but always interested in learning something new.  Here is the setup; I have three tables, container_location, container_location_size and container.  Yes there is a location table also, but I do not believe that I need it here. The container_location is a join table that lists the containers that are at a given location.  The container table describes the characteristics for a given container.  The container_location_size describes how containers can be put into a location.  I can get the number of containers for a given location with this SQL:

```
SELECT location_code,
       COUNT(*) AS container_count
  FROM container_location
GROUP BY location_code
```

The question I am trying to answer is which locations are full (i.e. have a number of containers equal to, or greater than, the max for that location.  The container_location_size table has a column max_containers that specifies how many containers can be at that location.  I have come up with this SQL to answer that question:

```
SELECT container_location_size.location_code
  FROM container_location_size
  JOIN (SELECT location_code,
               COUNT(*) AS container_count
          FROM container_location
        GROUP BY location_code) AS contcount
    ON contcount.location_code = container_location_size.location_code
 WHERE contcount.container_count >= container_location_size.max_containers
```

This works but I am wondering if this can be done as a single select.  The issue I ran into is that `HAVING` requires that any column being compared be in the `GROUP BY`.  I obviously do not want to group by the max number of containers.  Like I said at the beginning I expect this is not a solvable problems, but I am interested in either being proven wrong, or alternate approaches.

Comment: Just add `max_containers` to the group by?

Comment: As I said in the question, this leads to the wrong count of the containers by location.  The "real" schema has more than one possible max containers since different containers have different sizes.  I used a simplified example, perhaps I over simplified the example.

Comment: I don't actually see where you said that in the question.. I think you may indeed have oversimplified. Are there multiple rows in `location` with the same `location_code` but different `max_containers` values?

Comment: I said, "I obviously do not want to group by the number of containers."  In the real schema I am not using location at all rather I am using container, container_location and container_location_size.  I thought it would be simpler but I now realize that it also dropped the issue.  The max_containers is in container_location_size by container_size_code.  Different containers have different maximum numbers that can be in a given location.  The issue is if I join this table in the select with the group by I get multiple rows (one for each container size. See Answer, Thanks.

Comment: You said that, but you didn't give any indication why that was "obvious" in the question. If you specify your real schema from the start, you'll get an answer much quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
SELECT l.location_code, COUNT(*) AS container_count
FROM container_location cl JOIN
     location l
     ON l.location_code = cl.location_code
GROUP BY l.location_code
HAVING COUNT(*) >= MAX(l.max_containers);
```

Notes:

- This assumes that `location(location_code)` is unique.  That seems reasonable.
- The `HAVING` clause uses `MAX(l.max_containers)`.  The column needs to be in an aggregate function.
- An alternative would be to include `l.max_containers` in the `GROUP BY`.
- This may not be much faster than your version.

Comment: As I have changed the question I will take your answer the last step.  container_location_size(location_code) is not unique, but container_location_size(location_code, container_size) is.  The trick about MAX is what put me over the top, thanks.

Comment: For those interested this is the SQL I ended up with:

    SELECT 'FULL' As occupancy,
         COUNT(*) as container_count
      FROM location loc
     JOIN container_location conloc
        ON conloc.location_code = loc.location_code
      JOIN container con
       ON con.container_code = conloc.container_code
      JOIN container_and_location_size coanls
        ON coanls.location_size_code = loc.location_size_code 
       AND coanls.container_size_code = con.container_size_code
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= MAX(coanls.max_number_of_containers)